# Python can't request with proxies to most servers

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I got the following code, proxy is a public proxy I found on [this](https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/) site.

```
import requests

proxies = {
    "https": "http://27.203.242.127:8060",
    "http": "http://27.203.242.127:8060"}

url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
url2 = "https://www.google.com/"
r1 = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
r2 = requests.get(url2, proxies=proxies, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
```

r1 runs just fine but I get a long error message when I try to run r2.

First error I get is "BadStatusLine" and from there a few "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:" spawning ProtocolError and ConnectionError.

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadStatusLine                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    661             if is_new_proxy_conn:
--> 662                 self._prepare_proxy(conn)
    663 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _prepare_proxy(self, conn)
    947         conn.set_tunnel(self._proxy_host, self.port, self.proxy_headers)
--> 948         conn.connect()
    949 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    307             # self._tunnel_host below.
--> 308             self._tunnel()
    309             # Mark this connection as not reusable

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _tunnel(self)
    915         response = self.response_class(self.sock, method=self._method)
--> 916         (version, code, message) = response._read_status()
    917 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    287             self._close_conn()
--> 288             raise BadStatusLine(line)
    289 

BadStatusLine: <html>


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    719             retries = retries.increment(
--> 720                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    721             )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    399             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 400                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    401             elif read is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    733             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 734                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    735             raise value

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    661             if is_new_proxy_conn:
--> 662                 self._prepare_proxy(conn)
    663 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _prepare_proxy(self, conn)
    947         conn.set_tunnel(self._proxy_host, self.port, self.proxy_headers)
--> 948         conn.connect()
    949 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    307             # self._tunnel_host below.
--> 308             self._tunnel()
    309             # Mark this connection as not reusable

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _tunnel(self)
    915         response = self.response_class(self.sock, method=self._method)
--> 916         (version, code, message) = response._read_status()
    917 

~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    287             self._close_conn()
--> 288             raise BadStatusLine(line)
    289 

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<html>\r\n'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-db3266a345e8> in <module>
      7 url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
      8 url2 = "https://www.google.com/"
----> 9 r = requests.get(url2, proxies=proxies, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<html>\r\n'))
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Hi Klaus, I have edited the post.

Comment: The proxy does not send back a proper HTTP response. It is faulty.

Comment: I have tried several proxies, from that site preciously mentioned and from https://www.sslproxies.org/ aswell. Are they all faulty?

Comment: I can only make a statement about the proxy raising the error you posted. It seems to miss the HTTP headers in its response.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need to initiate a session for certain request. I have no idea if this is one, but I'd give that a go:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = {
  “http”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,
  “https”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,
}
r = s.get(“http://toscrape.com”)
```

This is referenced from [here](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/python-requests-proxy). Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Jesse, that did not work unfortunately. Only got a slightly different error message.

Comment: the second URL is __HTTPS__ and is being sent without credentials, not sure if that is an issue, and also if the CA bundles are an issue you can try in your `requests.get(url, verify=False)` to see if it's the bundles causing an issue, but I'm not sure where else to go from there at this point.